# Development build errors showing in production build on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, error-handling, production-environment

I have a NodeJS app, built with ReactJS, deployed on Heroku which is showing errors that should only be visible in a development build (See picture below).

[Development errors showing in production build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRpTE.png)

I have tried deploying this project to Heroku using both the node.js buildpack and the create-reat-app buildpack.

When I deploy the app locally using an optimised production build these errors do not show up (npm run build). I thought this command was run when deploying the app to Heroku, so I do not know why these errors still appear.

I have tried setting the config variables: NODE_ENV=production and NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true.

Is there some other way I should be deploying this app in order for it to create a proper production build on Heroku?

Comment: Unless specifically told otherwise, heroku just run `npm start`. Maybe you can try looking in your `package.json` file to see what `start` does.

Comment: @declan There's Heroku config variables, as well as local config variables. I'm not sure which you have set.

Comment: Yeah I have set the config variables in Heroku

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was a matter of changing the Heroku buildpack back to https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git and adding a 'heroku-postbuild' script of 'npm run build' to the 'scripts' section of the package.json.